# Adding $k\pi$ vs adding $2k\pi$ in solutions to trig inequalities involving tangent or cotangent

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

An author usually adds $k\pi$ to solutions of a trigonometric inequality that includes tangent or cotangent. However, in this example,
$$\log_{\tan{x}}{\sin{x}}>1$$ 
he used $2k\pi$, so that the solutions are: 
$$x\in\left(2k\pi,\frac{\pi}{4}+2k\pi\right)$$

> What made him use $2k\pi$ instead of just $k\pi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely to  do with the presence of $\sin x$ as well as $\tan x$. See the graphs [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uwvmmog6fu) and [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wlixvczqlw) - all have a period of $2\pi$